# How to efficiently write a function for this?

Tags: c++, multithreading, function

I have a long string which I separate to shorter strings and parallelize them. How to write a function which passes the thread count and separates the string to that many shorter segments?

This is how I've been doing

```
//Thread count is 4
seg = content.length() / 4;

string dataSeg1, dataSeg2, dataSeg3, dataSeg4;

dataSeg1 = content.substr(0, seg);
dataSeg2 = content.substr(seg, seg * 2);
dataSeg3 = content.substr(seg * 2, seg * 3);
dataSeg4 = content.substr(seg * 3, seg * 4);

thread t1(printLen, dataSeg1);
thread t2(printLen, dataSeg2);
thread t3(printLen, dataSeg3);
thread t4(printLen, dataSeg4);

if (t1.joinable())
{
t1.join();
}
if (t2.joinable())
{
t2.join();
}
if (t3.joinable())
{
t3.join;
}
if (t4.joinable())
{
t4.join();
}
```

What is a better way to write this?

Comment: Have you tried using std::vector?

Comment: I'm new to c++, from my py exp I just converted what I could in the above code. Can you tell me how to use vector for this?

Comment: If you are familiar with any other languages, std::vector is like an array or list. It can hold a variable number of items, and you can use a `for` loop to populate the vector. You can find some examples at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector.

Comment: The logic of the function is where I'm stuck. How to populate it as per user-defined segments?

Comment: I'm not sure where you are stuck, can you update the question to include your attempt and show which part you need help with?

Comment: Your question title is rather uninformative. Please review the advice in [ask] about writing good question titles.

Comment: Maybe because each string is composed of several tightly-wound threads :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use a loop because you have a number of lines of code that are almost identical.

Using your code as a base:

```
static const unsigned int numberOfThreads = 4;
const size_t segmentLength = content.length() / numberOfThreads;
std::vector<thread> threads;
for (int threadCount = 0; threadCount < numberOfThreads; ++threadCount)
{
  threads.push_back(thread(printLen, content.substr((seg * threadCount), ((seg+1) * threadCount));
}
for (auto thread : threads)
{
  if (thread.joinable())
    thread.join();
}
```

This is just the next step (I haven't compiled it), there are still issues you will need to handle, such as what happens if content.Length() is not divisible by 4.  There is going to be a better way of handling the has the thread finished check as well.

Hopefully it should help you a bit.